# How to add search box to table results in admin page

Tags: search

I have a custom database that i succesfully brought into my plugin submenu page and it displays the results great. If you manually add a row to the DB with phpmyadmin it shows that result on a refresh. Here's a screen shot of result page from that database here:-> http://prntscr.com/mropc3 
CODE below:

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>First Name</th> 
  <th>Last Name</th> 
  <th>Buyer's Email Address</th>
  <th>Software Title</th> 
  <th>IP Address 01</th> 
  <th>IP Address 02</th>
  <th>Payment Status</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $ipn_tables = $wpdb->prefix ."ipn_data_tbl";

        $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $ipn_tables" );
        foreach ( $result as $print )   {
        ?>
           <tr>     
           <td><?php echo $print->first_name;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $print->last_name;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $print->payer_email;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $print->item_name;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $print->ip_address_01;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $print->ip_address_02;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $print->payment_status;?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php }
  ?></table>
```

I pre added a search box but how to search this html table and
show results from a search. 
Have been looking all day and tried the above code repeated twice in two different functions then tried this:

```
<form>
    <form method="post" action="" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Transactions.." name="submit">
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Search" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" class="button-primary" value="Reset Form">
</form>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
  // there is something in the field, do stuff
  $search = $_POST["search"];
  return_esb_searches ();
  echo "searching";
} else {
  // trigger normal results
  all_esb_results ();
 echo "showing normal results display without search";
}
```

In the 'search' function i tried:

```
 $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$ipn_tables} WHERE item_name like $search OR first_name like $search OR last_name like $search OR payer_email like $search" ));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why didn't the code post correctly..?
it was meant to look like : http://prntscr.com/mroyhy   <- this works
this is what i tried... but didnt post above correctly  http://prntscr.com/mroyyq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<form method="post" action="" >
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Transactions.." name="submit">
<input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Search" name="submit">
<input type="reset" class="button-primary" value="Reset Form">
</form>
```

should be

```
<form method="post" action="" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Transactions.." name="search">
   <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Search" name="submit">
   <input type="reset" class="button-primary" value="Reset Form">
</form>
```

i.e. Remove extra start tag `<form>` and for text field `name="submit"` should be  `name="search"`

I hope this will work!

Comment: Hi Qaisar,
tried that thanks but it returns a blank page. I am wondering if something is wrong in my second function. I pasted both here: https://pastebin.com/6ZSTxgEH
I'm sure there's an easier simpler way to do it. Without the second function and without any search it works. Just want to add a simple search feature so can find a person or item in case list grows too big.
I'll keep plodding away..learning lots.. :) If you or anyone can see something obviously wrong with my code be great. Its a private d/L  ..just trying to make it a bit easier for them.Thank you.

Comment: returns a blank page? Do you mean a page with no search results or a page with no html contents?

Comment: I noticed when i click my submenu page that code is on the full table of results show this: example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=esb_softwares_slg
When i click the submit button and search for name "ben" my page shows this: example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?search=ben&submit=search and i get a blank page...am i expecting to be on same page but search function to run instead? It's late and i'm tired...so i must be missing something obvious 0_o ?

Comment: OK, take rest now. Setting `action` attribute of form may resolve the issue of blank page, 
`<form method="post" action="?page=esb_softwares_slg" >`

Comment: Still blank unfortunately and not sure if that action attrib was meant to append to url string in browser bar but its not. WOW..its so late. going to bed and maybe think about it in the morning...but, my pastebin code..does it look right? goodnight.

Comment: Using POST method, form data should not be visible in browser's address bar like this     `...?search=ben&submit=search`.   
Your pastebin code  looks right.

Comment: You should activate WP_DEBUG in your wp-config.php, there must be errors from PHP.

Comment: Had that on as well as when i get a php error i already get a log in that folder i am working in, ie my plugin folder. but this problem gives no errors. It's got me baffled. I don't want to move This thread to chat as need some other eyes to have a look but thanks to Qaisar for your help. 
Is a simple search not possible? A complete reword of what i am asking:
I have this table pulling into a page of my plugin--> https://prnt.sc/mropc3
That code is this:  https://pastebin.com/Y9xEPZtH
Question: How to create a simple search to return just names on this SAME plugin page??

Comment: @Schmutly Got the culprit! Answer  updated. Now check and let me know if sql part works or not.

Comment: BRILLIANT!! 
Thank you...see here-->  http://prntscr.com/ms2xpo
I do have a self-inflicted error lol but i will sort that. The result returned as i put the first_name ='ben' without variable to test. So i have an issue there but it works and  i can go from here.
I learned something from the form issue 0_o didn't realize that either..when you stuck in a mindset like i was you miss things too easily.
Thanks again Qaisar  :) GREAT.

Comment: @Schmutly Stay blessed! Always.